# Problem regarding finding an eigen value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Problem regarding **Daniel A. Spielman**   Lecture Notes in **Spectral Graph Theory**:

He writes that if $\lambda_1,\lambda_2...\lambda_n$ are eigen values of the Laplacian Matrix $M$ then

$\lambda_1=\min _{x\neq \underline 0}\dfrac{x^TMx}{x^Tx}$ and let $x_1$ be eigen vector corresponding to $\lambda_1$

and the second eigen value $\lambda_2=\min _{x\neq \underline 0;x\perp x_1}\dfrac{x^TMx}{x^Tx}$.

Question:**I am unable to understand why he takes $x\perp x_1$ in the computation  of $2nd$ eigen value.**

In the $3rd$ he takes $x\perp x_1,x\perp x_2$ .Why so ?

Any help will be highly helpful.

Comment: The laplacian is a symmetric matrix so eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal (elementary observation). However you may look at the *Theorem of Courant-Fisher* (or *min-max-Theorem*), since it is the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A symmetric matrix of order $n\times n$ always contains $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors which spans the space. Also the eigenvectors are orthogonal to each other. Therefore when you get the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue, the next eigenvector should be searched in the space which is not a constant multiple of the first, i.e. a space other than the span of the first eigenvector. Hence it is orthogonal to the first eigenvector. The further arguments could be made similarly. This is true for all symmetric matrices.